# Quantiles in R for above an upper percentage

Tags: r, quantile

Any ideas on how to calculate the quantile of a sample data that are at or above the upper 1%? 
From what I understand quantile(X, 0.99) will bring me the value of the sample that the 99%  is below it.

Thanks

Comment: Not clear what you ask. But this will give you the actual values that are above your 99% quantile: `x = rnorm(1000, 5,5);
q = quantile(x, 0.99);
x[x > q]`

Comment: what's the difference? You can make it more accurate by `quantile(X,0.990000001)`.

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier to demonstrate with actual code.

Do something like..

```
library(dplyr)

DF <- DF %>%
      filter(column > quantile(column, 0.99))
```